# Is it possible to get the URL for google sheet in .dsv format?

Tags: csv, url, google-sheets, export

I've just discovered the possibility to export a google sheet in csv format but I actually need the separator to be a "|" and not a ","
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Not possible. Here are the possible export MIME types for spreadsheets: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats. Maybe you could convert from csv to dsv after exporting?

Comment: Unfortunately not: a booking software needs an url to download my availability in a csv format (using pipe) on an hourly basis (so I cant do it manually). I found a way with a script to download a csv in the right format to my google drive but then can't give a URL to the booking software...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (You will probably have to encapsulate the data with quotes.). Here the file is stored in 'test' folder (to be adapted to your project).

```
const where = 'test' // here the name of folder where you want to record the file
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('* Export ... *')
    .addItem('... to .dsv format !', 'createDSVFile')
    .addToUi();
}
// you have to declare a trigger on onEdit
function onEdit(event){
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sh.getName()=='mySheet'){
    createDSVFile()
  }
}
function createDSVFile() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();
  var lc=sh.getLastColumn();
  var sep = '|';
  var txt = '';
  for (var i=1;i<=lr;i++){
    for (var j=1;j<=lc;j++){
      txt += sh.getRange(i,j).getValue() + sep
    }
    txt = txt.substring(0,txt.length-1) + '\n'
  }
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(where);
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    saveData(folder, 'myDSVFile.dsv',txt);
  }
}
function saveData(folder, fileName, content) {
  var children = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  var file = null;
  if (children.hasNext()) {
    file = children.next();
    file.setContent(content);
  } else {
    file = folder.createFile(fileName, content);
  }
  toast('File "' + fileName + '" recorded !')
}
function toast(body, title, timeout) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(
    body,
    title || "information",
    timeout || 5 // In seconds
  );
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h1xXLEOScw2duqydJwtBvZcsfO2vHI05WOf3fojC6VI/copy

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks a lot for your help and assistance. sorry I am quite a newbie here and need a little bit more time to figure it out... I have copied my data into your "test sheet" but don't know how to deploy the script. (I don't think I have ever used Advanced drive service, so not too sure how to activate it... Will this script provide a URL for the robots to download the correct dsv file on an hourly basis? (or does it save it into my google drive = no URL for the robot) I will look into this tomorrow and hopefully find how to make it work :) Thank you!

Comment: First, create a folder 'test' in your dirve. Then take a new copy of my spreadsheet, you will see a menu called * Export ... *. You will have (one time) to authorize google to run the script. You will be able to create a different folder and mentioned it in the script at the first instruction.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike, that worked! Will the script run by itself on a regular basis? or do I need to run it manually? Ideally I would like it to run after anything change in the "source" file.

Comment: I updated my proposal for this, only if the data change is done manually. You will have to declare a trigger on onEdit function in that case. If the modification is done automatically by a foreign program, please include createDSVFile in your program

Comment: @MikeSteelson As per my previous edit, this script is not using [Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), just plain [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive). It also doesn't use [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2), which is a different API than Drive. Therefore, please consider not rolling back my edit again, since that mention can be confusing for the OP and for others looking at this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I apologize if I do something wrong on your previous fix. My English is not at the highest level and I am more of a gas newbee with less than six months of experience. What I understand is that I have nothing more to do since you corrected the answer. I will deepen my understanding of the Drive API. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To download a specific sheet as a CSV file, replace {key} with the document's ID and {sheet_name} with the name of the sheet to export:

> [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet_name}](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%7Bkey%7D/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=%7Bsheet_name%7D)

Comment: Thank you for you reply. This will give me a CSV file (comma separated), I need it to be pipe separated "|"